# Electric field due to a solid sphere of charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, coulombs-law

I have been trying to understand the last step of this derivation. Consider a sphere made up of charge $+q$. Let $R$ be the radius of the sphere and $O$, its center.

A point $P$ lies inside the sphere of charge. In such a case, Gaussian surface is a spherical shell,whose center is $O$ and radius is $r$ (=OP). If $q'$ is charge enclosed by Gaussian surface,then

$$E\times4\pi r^2=q'/\epsilon$$ where $\epsilon=$ absolute permittivity of free space.

$$E=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon}\times(q'/r^2)$$  for $(r<R)$

$$q'=\frac{q}{\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3}\times\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3=\frac{qr^3}{R^3}$$

Comment: Hello Drown, Welcome to Physics.SE. Here, we make use of TeX - an useful resource for formulas. Please have a look my revision of your question. It would be useful if you could modify the content to ask specifically what you require from now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume your problem is the calculation of $q'=\frac{r^3}{R^3}q$.

This is perhaps easier to explain by splitting the calculation in two steps. The solid ball of charge is supposed to be homogeneous, so it has a charge density
$$
\rho=\frac{\textrm{total charge}}{\textrm{total volume}}=\frac{q}{\frac{4\pi}{3}R^3}.
 $$
The smaller sphere has volume $V_r=\frac{4\pi}{3}r^3$, and therefore has charge
$$q'=\rho V_r=\frac{q}{\frac{4\pi}{3}R^3}\frac{4\pi}{3}r^3=\frac{r^3}{R^3}q.$$

Comment: From where did you get this formula q′=ρVr. While studying i never got this formula.

Comment: That $\rho$ is called charge density which is the charge per unit volume. $\rho=q/V$. This is the same as linear and surface charge densities...

Answer (score 0):

$$E= \frac{kQr}{R^3} \\ = \frac{\rho r}{3 \epsilon_0}$$

Comment: Hi, it's best to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts for both clarity and readability. When writing answers, it is also best to give an explanation rather than just an answer.

Answer (score -3):

[image]Electric field due to solid sphere.This is so easy.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Physics SE! Please do not post screenshots as answers. Write equations using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that search engines can index this post.

Comment: If its so easy how did u get the completely wrong answer LOL