# Sphere of electric charge revisited

Tags: electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, gauss-law, coulombs-law

I am thinking about a sphere of homogeneous charge distribution (see [Electric field due to a solid sphere of charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41667/electric-field-due-to-a-solid-sphere-of-charge), for example).

[image: Setup: Charge imagined to be to the right of the light blue circle at a distance a from the center.]

Here we use a Gaussian surface (blue area) to find the electric field
$$
\epsilon_0 4\pi a^2 E = \frac{3Q_{sphere}}{4\pi R^3}\frac{4\pi a^3}{3} 
$$

I am told that if I were to put a test charge at $a=\frac{R}{2}$, it would feel a force of magnitude $F = qE$, $E$ calculated from above. This is something that intuitively doesn't make sense to me: If we think of the sphere as one that contains a lot of small charges $dq$, wouldn't all the $dq$'s to the right of the charge have an influence that would cancel some of the force exerted from the blue area? Sure, there is a green area at the other side of the blue area but the distance would mean that the electric field it generates would fall of and the situation wouldn't be symmetric.

**Why doesn't the charge outside of the Gaussian surface contribute to the force?**

Comment: See [Newton's shell theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem). Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18446/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2481/2451 and links therein, if electric charge and Coulomb's law are replaced by mass and Newton's law of universal gravitation, respectively.

Comment: @Qmechanic why not just write a short answer that says this, before someone else does.